# Send angularjs Data ID to my node server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I would like to send ID to my node server.

but I don't know how to get it server side. The Req is sent.
console.log(req.body) returned empty...

**Controller:**

```js
$scope.remove = function(id) {
    var idstring = JSON.parse(id);
    $http.delete('/contactlist/remove', {data: idstring}).then(function(response){
        $scope.contactlist = $scope.contactlist.filter(function(contact){
            return contact.id !== id;
        })
    });
};
```

**Server:**

```js
app.delete('/contactlist/remove', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    // connection.query('DELETE FROM contactlist WHERE id = ' + req.body.id, function (error, results, fields) {
    res.json();
    // });
});
```

**Screenshot of DELETE request in chrome:** 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send data in delete method

so make delete url like `/contactlist/remove/3`

```
$http.delete('/contactlist/remove/'+idstring).then(function(response){
        $scope.contactlist = $scope.contactlist.filter(function(contact){
            return contact.id !== id;
        })
    });
```

On server side

```
app.delete('/contactlist/remove/:idstring', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.idstring);
    connection.query('DELETE FROM contactlist WHERE id = ' + req.params.idstring, function (error, results, fields) {
    res.json();
    });
});
```